# Find siblings in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<incollection mdate="2017-05-16" key="reference/algo/NaFGP08"
              publtype="encyclopedia entry"> 
  <author>Joong Chae Na</author>  
  <author>Paolo Ferragina</author>  
  <author>Raffaele Giancarlo</author>  
  <author>Kunsoo Park</author>  
  <title>Two-Dimensional Pattern Indexing.</title>  
  <year>2008</year>  
  <booktitle>Encyclopedia of Algorithms</booktitle>  
  <ee>https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-30162-4_442</ee>  
  <crossref>reference/algo/2008</crossref>  
  <url>db/reference/algo/algo2008.html#NaFGP08</url> 
</incollection>
```

How can I select all the coauthors of Paolo Ferragina with XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/incollection[author = 'Paolo Ferragina']/author
```

will select all of the co-authors of Paolo Ferragina, assuming one can be a co-author of oneself.

Without that assumption, this XPath

```
/incollection[author = 'Paolo Ferragina']/author[. != 'Paolo Ferragina']
```

will exclude Paolo Ferragina.

Or, to more literally find the siblings of Paolo Ferragina:

```
//author[preceding-sibling::author[. = 'Paolo Ferragina'] or 
         following-sibling::author[. = 'Paolo Ferragina']]
```